# rake asset:precompile for rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

i have deployed a rails application on heroku
ruby version 1.9.3-p547
rails version 2.3.18

while i am using webrick server its working properly,but using unicorn server its not working ,that means it didn't support javascript, css and all,it shows error like this

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/search.jpg" with {:method=>:get}):

so i have tried this command $ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
but it shows error like this

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'

in rails 2.3.18 not even have assets.please help me to solve this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no assets pipeline in rails 2.3. You need to put `search.jpg` in `public/images/` to access it through `/images/search.jpg`.

For javascripts and stylesheets they are the same. All you need is to create a folder `public/javascripts` and `public/stylesheets` and put your files into them accordingly.

To access them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/example.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/example.css" />
```

Comment: here my application javascript and css also not working how to solve this?